# Python regular expression: find "com" or "org"

Tags: python, regex

Just want to find first time appearance of "com" OR "org".
I have tried:

```
comIndex = domain.index(r '(?: com|org)')
```

But it does not work. Could someone correct me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
re.search('(com)|(org)',domain).span()[0]
```

Comment: That's also a suboptimal solution because it throws an AttributeError exception if it doesn't find it, which I doubt is the OP's wish.

Comment: @Josh Morrison **span()** is the tuple (start,end) of a catched group, so **span()[0]** is the start's position of the catched group. But **start()** gives this start's position, too

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

comIndex = -1
m = re.search(r'(?:com|org)', domain)
if m:
    comIndex = m.start()
print comIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use regex like this. Regex in Python is not a built-in feature, and you need to [import the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html) to use the methods inside.

```
import re
...
comMatch = re.search('com|org', domain)
if comMatch:
   comIndex = comMatch.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pat = re.compile ('com|org')

ch = 'ABCDcomFGH'
print pat.search(ch).start() if pat.search(ch) else -1

ch = 'ABorgWDE'
print pat.search(ch).start() if pat.search(ch) else -1

ch = ':;,"?::/+=&'
print pat.search(ch).start() if pat.search(ch) else -1
```

result

```
4
2
-1
```